# Find the c.d.f. of X

Tags: probability

John has an insurance policy on his car with a 200\$ deductible, meaning that if an accident occur, he would pay the cost of the repair up to 200\$ with the insurance policy paying the rest. So if he has an accident worth 123\$ he would pay 123\$ but if the accident is worth 345\$ he would only pay 200\$.
Assume that the cost of an accident is uniformly distributed over [50, 1000]. Denote X the amount that John pays.

Compute the c.d.f. of X

Is X discrete, continuous, or neither discrete nor continuous

What is the probability that $X=200$

My attempt:

I would think that X is continuous because it is a piece-wise function, where John pays whatever the price of the damage is until 200\$ and then he pays 200\$ up to 1000\$.

Let t=cost of damage and F(t)=amount that John pays

Then the c.d.f would look like:

\begin{equation}
F(t)=
\begin{cases}
0\quad\quad\quad\quad t<50\\
\frac{t-50}{200-50}\quad\quad 50\leq t<200\\
\frac{t-200}{1000-200}\quad\;\; 200\leq t<1000\\
1\quad\quad\quad\quad  t<1000\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

For the last question, I am not sure how to find a probability from a c.d.f. Can I also get verification on my last two answers? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $C$ be the cost of an accident. Then $C\sim U[50,1000]$. Now we can express $X$ in terms of $C:$ $$X=\begin{cases}
C, & 50\le C<200\\
200, & 200\le C\le 1000
\end{cases}$$
Note that $\mathbb P(200\le C<1000)=\frac{1000-200}{1000-50}=\frac{16}{19}$. So naturally $X=200$ with probability $\frac{16}{19}$.

Also note that $X$ is neither a discrete nor continuous r.v., as $X$ has a point probability at $X=200$ (for continuous r.v.s, $\mathbb P(X=x)=0\:\forall x$)

Regarding the cdf, we want the cdf to increase linearly up to $1-\frac{16}{19}=\frac{3}{19}$ on $[50,200)$, and then reach $1$ once $x$ approaches $200$. It is easy to see that $$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & x<50\\
\frac{x-50}{1000-50}=\frac{x-50}{950}, & 50\le x<200\\
1, & x\ge 200
\end{cases}$$